# Pythonic way to parse a formatted text file

Tags: python, parsing, text-files

in my way to learn python the right way i want to parse a text file formatted this way:

```
game (
    name "Chess (1981)(M.C. Rakaska, S.W. Huggins) [Strategy, Chess].zip"
    file ( name Chess.bas size 19129 date 2007/01/31 19:46:20 crc 50577473 )
    file ( name Chess.exe size 46464 date 1998/12/25 19:46:00 crc 826d1c0d )
    file ( name file_id.diz size 198 date 2014/11/23 07:53:32 crc 72399680 )
)
```

With multiple entries like that.

AFAIK after reading here and there there are many ways to do it. I could parse it by hand (strippin, looking for data, etc), i could use some kind of regexp to parse lines, even i've found a module PyParse (a bit complex for me).

I am sure there is a more pythonic way that doing it by hand, maybe using PyParse? Doing it by hand seems a fast hack...

These kind of files come inside zip files, many are around 50MB, but i've already solved that loading the text file in memory, and stripping the header.

Any tips for doing the right way?

Comment: You have to have a defined grammar or syntax for what you're trying to parse. Which solutions that are suitable depends on that.

Comment: Manually parsing can be tedious but if you are new to python then it can  be good practise for getting to grips with data structures such as lists and dicts

Comment: kezzos: i was thinking the same, much more tedious and have to check many things but at the end it will better for learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it depends on irregularities in the data.
There are two complications that I can see here;

1. The name of the game is surrounded by double quotes. But what if the name also *contains* double qoutes?
2. What if the filenames contains spaces?

It looks like both problems can be adequately dealt with using regular espressions from the built-in `re` module. So keeping in mind the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) there is no real need to make it more complicated and use a full parser in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after reading here and there and many testing i came to this.

It's a extract of bigger loop where i parse other type of data in the file.
Coming from other languages (c++,Pascal,PHP) is a little strange for me the way python 3.x works with strings. I discovered that reading from inside ZIP file i got string in binary format (as bytes), so i must use "b" in a lot of sites, etc. But maybe this is material for another question.

Anyway, this worked for me.

```
gdregex = re.compile(r"file\s*\(\s*name\s+(.+)\s+size\s+(\d+)\s+date\s+(.+)\s+crc\s+([0-9a-fA-F]{8})\s*\)", re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)

with zipfile.ZipFile(dat_file) as datz:
    with datz.open('filetoprocess.txt') as datf:
        for line in datf:
            line=line.strip().lower()
            if line.startswith(b"game ("):
            # New entry
                is_new_entry = True
                entry = []
                continue
            if is_new_entry:
                if line.startswith(b"name"):
                    gamename = str(line[len("name")+2:])
                if line.startswith(b"file"):
                    line = str(line)
                    gamedatarx = gdregex.split(line,0)
                    entry = []
                    entry.append(gamename)
                    entry.extend(gamedatarx[1:4])
                    print(entry)
            if line==b')' and is_new_entry:
                is_new_entry = False
```